# How can set data on TextField from DatePicker

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator

I'm building a custom modal in appcelerator studio.

So this is the code:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="modal_add_edit" onClose="cleanup" modal="true">
        <View class="container">
            <Label id="title" class="title"/>
            <View class="separator"></View>

            <TableView id="table" height="Titanium.UI.SIZE" layout="vertical">                          
                    <TableViewRow class="menu_item" top="25">
                        <Label id="description" class="label" left="12" />
                        <Picker id="comboDecription" left="20" selectionIndicator="true">
                            <PickerColumn id="column1">
                                <PickerRow title="Esposizione Tossica"/>
                                <PickerRow title="Stato civile"/>
                                <PickerRow title="Diet"/>
                            </PickerColumn>
                        </Picker>
                    </TableViewRow>

                    <!-- flags -->
                    <TableViewRow id="data" class="menu_item" top="25">
                        <!--DATA START-->
                        <Label id="start_date" class="label" left="12" />
                        <TextField id="textStartDate" class="field"
                             width="200px"></TextField>
                    </TableViewRow>



            </TableView>

            <View class="separator"></View>
            <TableView id="tableButton" width="Titanium.UI.FILL" layout="horizontal">                           
                    <TableViewRow class="menu_item" top="25">
                        <Button id="buttonClose" class="buttonClose" onClick="onClose" ></Button>
                        <Button id="buttonSave" class="buttonSave"></Button>
                    </TableViewRow> 
            </TableView>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

So I want that if the user click on textStartdate, the DatePicker is showing. This is the code of my controller:

```
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({});
$.textStartDate.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    picker.showDatePickerDialog({
        value : new Date(), // some date
        callback : function(e) {
            if (e.cancel) {
                Ti.API.info('user canceled dialog');
            } else {
                selectedDate = e.value;
                $.textStartDate.setValue(String.formatDate(selectedDate, 'medium'));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then if I try to click on textStartDate, I can see the DatePicker, then I set the data, click on OK button but I can't display the data on textStartDate.

If I can try in debug, the code:

```
String.formatDate(selectedDate, 'medium')
```

return the correct data but I can't see it on my edittext

**edit**
I add the screen shot

[image]

this is the class of field in app.tss

```
".field": {
    left: "5%",
    width: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    borderRadius: 5,
    hintTextColor: "#aaa",
    color: "#333",
    backgroundColor: "white"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that `String.formatDate(selectedDate, 'medium')` is returning correct data, but you cannot see the date, so I can guess that it might be the problem with your text-field color properties.

Make sure that you have set the color property to different one than the text-field backgroundColor, or if you have not set any such property, then I still suggest you to set ***color*** and ***backgroundColor*** properties and some default value to make sure that your text value is properly visible in the text field.

Sometimes depending on themes or OS type, default text color & backgroundColor combinations could be same which makes the text value invisible.

Comment: that string, return the correct string, but if I try to set "pippo" is the same. The background color of textfield is different from color of text

Comment: Can you confirm by setting default value property to anything and share the screenshot? or just share some code so that I can check it here

Comment: Ok one moment and I share the screen shot. But if I try to go on debug, after the code where I set the value of textStartdate, If I try to inspect on textStartdate the value is correct but it is not show

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, but from my last comment I meant that set the default value on text field in tss or in xml so that you can see some value before clicking on the text field.